# Simple Save/Load the entire array

Tags: iphone, xcode3.2

I'm new. Been trying to save/load a couple of arrays but to no avail.
I have "Global.h" and "Global.m" providing arrays for other classes.

in Global.h

```
extern NSMutableArray *arrayTable;
extern NSMutableArray *arrayPurpose;
@interface Global : NSObject <NSCoding> {
}
```

in Global.m

```
NSMutable *arrayTable;
MSMutable *arrayPurpose;
```

I have other views/controllers/classes/whatever that work with these arrays and they are functioning. What do I put inside this "Global" and the "AppDelegate.h" and "AppDelegate.m" so that these arrays are saved when this app goes into background and loads when the app starts? I need to use this "NSDocumentDirectory" because this data is important.

Please keep your explanations REALLLLLLY EASY. I have less than a week's experience. Thanks!!

Edit: Did what Joris suggested.
Added this to the AppDelegate

```
-(NSString *)archivePath {
NSString *docDir =
[NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory,NSUserDomainMask, YES)objectAtIndex: 0];
return [docDir stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"TableData.dat"];
}

- (void)applicationDidEnterBackground:(UIApplication *)application {
[NSKeyedArchiver archiveRootObject:arrayTable toFile:self.archivePath];
    [NSKeyedArchiver archiveRootObject:arrayPurpose toFile:self.archivePath];
}

- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {  
[window addSubview:rootController.view];
[self.window makeKeyAndVisible];

arrayTable = [NSKeyedUnarchiver unarchiveObjectWithFile:[self archivePath]];
arrayPurpose = [NSKeyedUnarchiver unarchiveObjectWithFile:[self archivePath]];
if (arrayTable == nil) {
    arrayPurpose = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
    arrayTable = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
}
return YES;
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not very detailed but:

in the suspend method of your appdelegate you can use:

```
[NSKeyedArchiver archiveRootObject:arrayTable toFile:...];
```

and in the resume method:

```
arrayTable = [[NSKeyedUnarchiver unarchiveObjectWithFile:...] retain];
```

Comment: Can you show me the whole thing? On how it's done? I've been trying these NSKeyedArchiver and NSKeyedUnarchiver for days and about to throw my mac out of my window.

Comment: The whole thing? The only things missing are: the exact method names in your appDelegate, but these should be straightforward, and the generation of the output file path

Comment: Did what you suggested. Declared "archivePath" for use. Then followed by NSKeyedArchiver and Unarchiver. Still doesn't work. Any idea why? Oh, and why does the unarchiver disallow me to add a . between the self and archivepath? It wont let me build.

Comment: you forgot to retain the arrays after unarchiving them